# PowerShell: Measure-Command outputs nice Response Time list to console; when outputted to text file its one very long string of text

Tags: html, powershell, loops, foreach, active-directory

I've found that the PowerShell Measure-Command outputs a nice Response Time list to console, but when outputted to text file it becomes one very long string of text.  This is a problem because it becomes hard to read when viewed with an HTML reader.  I've struggled with this one for quite a bit this evening, so now posting this to SO.

```
import-module activedirectory
cls
$myForest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
$domaincontrollers = $myforest.Sites | % { $_.Servers } | Select Name
$report = foreach ($DomainController in $DomainControllers) 
{
  $totalmeasurement = 0
  $i = 0
  while ($i -ne $numberoftests)
  {
  $measurement = (Measure-Command {Get-ADUser Administrator -Server $DomainController.name}).TotalSeconds
  $totalmeasurement += $measurement
  $i += 1
  }
  $totalmeasurement = $totalmeasurement / $numberoftests
  "Domain Controller: " + $DomainController.name + ", Response time: " + $totalmeasurement + " seconds"
}
```

The above code when run inside a vanilla environment will produce output looking like this first screenshot:
[image: Pretty Result]

---

With a slight modification to the code (as shown below) by setting **foreach** to a variable:

```
import-module activedirectory
cls
$myForest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
$domaincontrollers = $myforest.Sites | % { $_.Servers } | Select Name
$report = foreach ($DomainController in $DomainControllers) 
{
  $totalmeasurement = 0
  $i = 0
  while ($i -ne $numberoftests)
  {
  $measurement = (Measure-Command {Get-ADUser Administrator -Server $DomainController.name}).TotalSeconds
  $totalmeasurement += $measurement
  $i += 1
  }
  $totalmeasurement = $totalmeasurement / $numberoftests
  "Domain Controller: " + $DomainController.name + ", Response time: " + $totalmeasurement + " seconds"
}
$report | Out-String | Out-File $htmlfile_temp -Append
```

The file output winds up looking the mess shown in this second screenshot:

[image: Messy Result]

I've tried many different permutations of the original code to output to the file formatted nicely as shown in the first screenshot, to no avail.  I've given up and am posting the question to this forum.  I am well aware of the limitations of write-host, and is one of many reasons I am outputting to an HTML file instead.

(Original code from this post found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26227.active-directory-measure-dc-response-time-with-powershell-when-running-ldap-query.aspx))

Comment: Try: `Out-String -Stream`. Running it without `-Stream`,  `Out-String` sends out **a** *formatted **string*** to the console. Using `-Stream` allows you to send each line, one at a time.

Comment: add a newline to the end of your `"Domain Controller: " + ` string builder line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to open the output in an HTML file. You would then need a `<br>` at the end of every line to see that information on separate line.

I have made some amendments to your script. The output is in HTML and i have used a CSS file to format the table.

```
import-module activedirectory
cls

$htmlfile_temp = "C:\Temp\DCAudit.html" # ***PLEASE CHANGE THIS***

$myForest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
$domaincontrollers = $myforest.Sites | % { $_.Servers } | Select Name


$Report = @()
$totalmeasurement = @()
foreach ($DomainController in $DomainControllers) 
{
    # Get information about domain controllers
    $DC = Get-ADDomainController $DomainController.name
    
    
    $totalmeasurement = 0
    $numberoftests = 4
    $i = 0
    while ($i -ne $numberoftests)
    {
      $measurement = (Measure-Command {Get-ADUser Administrator -Server $DomainController.name}).TotalSeconds
      $totalmeasurement += $measurement
      $i += 1
    }
    $totalmeasurement = $totalmeasurement / $numberoftests
  
    # Create a Hash Table
    $Hash = @{
        DomainController = $DomainController.NAME
        ResponseTimeInSeconds =  $totalmeasurement
        DateTime = (get-date)
        Forest = $Dc.forest
        IPAddress = $DC.IPv4Address
        OS = $DC.OperatingSystem
        Site = $Dc.Site

    }
  [array]$Report += New-Object psobject -Property $Hash
}

# Define CSS
$CSS = "
<style>
h1 { font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, Optima, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 24px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 700; 
    line-height: 26.4px; } 
h2 { font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, Optima, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 18px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 700; 
    line-height: 15.4px; }
h3 { font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, Optima, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 700; 
    line-height: 15.4px; } 
body{ font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, Optima, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-style: normal; 
    font-variant: normal; 
    font-weight: 400; 
    line-height: 15px; }
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
</style>
"

$Report | ConvertTo-Html -Head $CSS | Out-File $htmlfile_temp
```

Answer (score 1):

When you build your report as array of **objects** instead of an array of **strings** you will have much more control of what the output should look like.
Below demonstrates two types of file output, one as structured CSV file you can open in Excel, the other shows how you can create a nice looking HTML file of the data:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$myForest          = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
$domaincontrollers = ($myforest.Sites | ForEach-Object { $_.Servers }).Name
$numberoftests     = 4  # just guessing..

$report = foreach ($dc in $DomainControllers) {
    $totalmeasurement = 0
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numberoftests) {
        $totalmeasurement += (Measure-Command {Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'Administrator'" -Server $dc}).TotalSeconds
    }
    # now output an object with the properties you need
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Domain Controller'       = $dc
        'Response Time (Seconds)' = ($totalmeasurement / $numberoftests)
    }
}

# output on screen
$report | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$report | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\ResponseTimes.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation

# output to HTML file
$htmlTemplate = @'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>ResponseTimes</title>"
    <style>
        body, table {font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #000000;}
        table {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
        th {border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 3px;}
        td {border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
@@TABLE@@
</body></html>
'@

$table = ($report | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment) -join [environment]::NewLine
$report  = $htmlTemplate -replace '@@TABLE@@', $table 
$report | Set-Content -Path 'X:\ResponseTimes.html'
```